# Need to use **kw in another method (not __init__)

Tags: python, python-3.x, self, keyword-argument

So, I have a class with an **init** method who have as argument **kw.
I need to use **kw in another method of the same class, but python return this error:
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'kw'

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        if kw is not None:
            for value in kw.items():
                self.value = value

    def showdata(self):
        if self.kw is not None:
            for value in self.kw.items():
                print("value: " + value)

obj1 = MyClass(A = 237, B = 83, C = 182218)
print(obj1.showdata())
```

Maybe is there another way to do that?
I've just started with OOP...

Comment: You're not storing anything at `self.kw` you are storing it at `self.value` but you are also writing over it every time so it will only store the last `kw` passed in initially.

Comment: @NielsHenkens kw is an actual argument though, it's just a variable-length mapping of parameters passed by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**kw` (i.e. keyword arguments) is saved as a local variable in the `__init__` function. What you need is to save it in the `self` argument to be an attribute of the class object.*

Your code should first save `**kw` as an attribute, then use it in another function (method) in the class, since you are passing the `self` argument.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.kw = kw

    def showdata(self):
        if self.kw:
            for key, value in self.kw.items():
                print(key, ":", value)

obj1 = MyClass(A = 237, B = 83, C = 182218)
obj1.showdata()
```

This code prints:

```
A : 237
B : 83
C : 182218
```

#### A few extra points:

- for a dictionary, you can use `if self.kw`. If it is empty, it will not go through the if statement.
- print("value" + value) only works if the variable `value` is of type `str` (string).
- `obj1.showdata()` already has `print` inside it, so you do not have to print the output of the function, because it returns `None`.

---

## *self

The `self` argument in Python refers to the current object. It has all the attributes of the object. That is why you can access `**kw` in another method of the class. I recommend [this website](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) if you are new to OOP in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with some little modification as stated below:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.kw = kw

    def showdata(self):
        if self.kw is not None:
            for key,value in self.kw.items():
                print(f'Key = {key} , Value = {value}')

obj1 = MyClass(A = 237, B = 83, C = 182218)
obj1.showdata()
```

Answer (score 0):

`**kw` gives you a list of all keyword arguments. By setting the variable `self.kw` to `kw` in the `__init__`you can use the keywords later.

And your for-loop in the `__init__` is overwriting `self.value` for every value. To solve that you could make self.value a list and append all values to it:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.kw = kw  # this sets the attribute kw of self to kw.
        if kw is not None:
            self.values = []
            for value in kw.items():
                self.values.append(value)

    def showdata(self):
        if values is not None:
            for value in values:
                print("value: " + value)

obj1 = MyClass(A = 237, B = 83, C = 182218)
print(obj1.showdata())
```

Because of that you are not using the names of the keywords you can change `**kw` to `*args` and set `self.values` to `args` instead:

```py
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.values = values  # this does the same thing as the code above but with much less code
```

If you are going to use this approach you should change `obj1 = MyClass(A = 237, B = 83, C = 182218)` to `obj1 = MyClass(237, 83, 182218)`